# Align horizontal border line with header div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, alignment

I have a header div that looks like this in css:

```
.page-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 20px
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%
  height: 40px;
}
```

and a border div under it:

```
.horizontal-line {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  margin: auto;
}
```

My problem is that I can't use padding on the border to make it align with the header or change the margin to fixed numbers, because then it doesn't center.

How would i go about fixing this so that the border adjust to the same width as the header?

Can it be done in CSS only? The reason I ask is that the JS is a template (not ideal I know) and there are other versions on the site using the same template (none of them are using the border div).

I've tried using max-width and that works really good on the large version of the site. Problem with that is that when the page is shrunk it doesn't dynamically adjust the max-width :(

Appreciate any help that I could get :)

Comment: Could you add your html also and try to give us a minimum reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you can add a container you can do something like this:
You can also add horizontal-line div inside the container and make it full 100% width and get the same result.

```css
.container {
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
.page-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 20px
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header"></div>
</div>
```

or put % on max-width and then when you resize screen it will resize this is not pretty i would rather choose to use container around it.

```css
.page-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 20px
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
/*   width: 100%; */
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.horizontal-line {
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-top: 50px;
 border-bottom: 2px black solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-header"></div>
<div class="horizontal-line"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I shall give them a try and get back to you :)